# CUDA compilation issue with CMake

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, cmake

I am having issues with compiling my CUDA code with CMake. I am using CUDA 7 and the version information from nvcc is as follows:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Dec__9_18:10:46_CST_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.17
```

My CMake file uses the find_cuda macro as follows:

```
find_package(CUDA)
if(CUDA_FOUND)
    list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_20;--compiler-options;-std=c++11;-O2;-DVERBOSE")
endif(CUDA_FOUND)
```

I added the std=c++11 compiler flag after many posts suggested this was needed. However, I get exactly the same errors with or without this flag.

I also added the following to remove the C++11 support from nvcc compilation flags but this does not change anything either.

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
    string(REPLACE "-std=c++11" "" CUDA_HOST_FLAGS "${CUDA_HOST_FLAGS}")
    string(REPLACE "-std=c++0x" "" CUDA_HOST_FLAGS "${CUDA_HOST_FLAGS}")
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
```

The errors I get are as follows:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h(432): error: expected
a ";"

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h(190): error: 
expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(63): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(68): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(76): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(83): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/exception(93): error: expected a "{"

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/exception_ptr.h(64): error: function 
"std::current_exception" returns incomplete type  
"std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr"
```

I am using gcc 4.8 but get the same errors with 4.7 as well. I am on cmake 2.8.12.2.

Compiling with CMAKE verbose gives the following flags for nvcc compilation:

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc /home/xargon/Dropbox/code/gpu-mosaicing
/src/gpu/kernels/bgra_2_gray.cu -c -o /home/xargon/code/mosaicing_bin
/gpu/kernels/CMakeFiles/kernels.dir//./kernels_generated_bgra_2_gray.cu.o 
-ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -DUSE_CUDA -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_QT -Xcompiler 
,\"-std=c++11\",\"-O3\",\"-DNDEBUG\" -arch=sm_20 --compiler-options 
-std=c++11 -O2 -DVERBOSE -DNVCC -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include -I/usr/local
/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/home/xargon/Dropbox/code/gpu-
mosaicing/src/cpu/gui/qt -I/usr/include -I/home/xargon/Dropbox/code/gpu-
mosaicing/src/cpu/core -I/home/xargon/Dropbox/code/gpu-mosaicing/src/cpu
/datasources -I/home/xargon/Dropbox/code/gpu-mosaicing/src/gpu
/intraoperability -I/home/xargon/Dropbox/code/gpu-mosaicing/src/utils 
-I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include
```

Comment: So, I get the following:
/bgra_2_gray.cu -c -o /home/xargon/code/mosaicing_bin/gpu/kernels/CMakeFiles/kernels.dir//./kernels_generated_bgra_2_gray.cu.o -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -DUSE_CUDA -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_QT -Xcompiler ,\"-std=c++11\",\"-O3\",\"-DNDEBUG\" -arch=sm_20 --compiler-options -std=c++11 -O2 -DVERBOSE -DNVCC

Comment: This Xcompiler stuff is plain stupid. You pass -std=c++11 so this is not an issue.

Comment: Ok, so the issue was to actually remove the std=c++11 flag. So, I had to set the CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS to OFF. However, I thought Cuda 7 supports C++ 11 features and I was wondering what is going on.

Comment: So the problem is solved?  How about if somebody provides an answer.

Comment: No, not solved. Only "solution" is to disable C++ 11 features and I really want to use C++ 11!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked for me using CUDA 7, gcc 4.8.2 and CMake 3.0.2.

**I updated the code and added a simple thrust-based example to make it clear that you can use C++11 in CUDA code**

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(cpp11)
find_package(CUDA)
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_20;-std=c++11;-O2;-DVERBOSE")
SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(cpp11 main.cpp test.h test.cu)
```

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
int run();
#endif
```

**test.cu**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

template<typename T>
struct Fun
{
        __device__ T operator()(T t1, T t2)
        {
            auto result = t1+t2;
            return result;
        }
};

int run()
{
    const int N = 100;
    thrust::device_vector<int> vec(N);
    thrust::sequence(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    auto op = Fun<int>();
    return thrust::reduce(vec.begin(),vec.end(),0,op);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << run() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *can* use C++11 in CUDA, please try out the extendend example.

Comment: You are right. This version works fine. There must be the C++11 detection in my CMakeLists that is doing something weird. Thanks for this though. I should be able to sort it out now.

Comment: In comparison to your example I do **not** use `--compiler-options`. Additionally, maybe consider upgrading CMake to the latest version.

Comment: Yes, I got it working. I did remove that option and set the propogate_host_flags option to false as well.

Comment: `SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)` is what did the trick for me when trying to use C++11 for the host code. I guess it's good to have this disabled, especially on large projects with lots of host flags.

Comment: Is it not possible to propagate a C++11 host compiler flag to CUDA?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus you can try compiling without `SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)` and see if it works for you

Comment: No such luck. Best I can tell, `CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS` propagates `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, the contents of which are not impacted by `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`. So doing `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=c++11")` and `set (CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)` will trigger C++11 everywhere. But I can't find a way to avoid explicitly setting `--std=c++11` in either CXX or CUDA flags.

Answer (score 11):

`list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++11")` is enough,`SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)` may be not necessary, and it cause me could not set breakpoint in .cu file

Comment: This also helped me in a project with many complicated dependencies. If I disabled propagating host flags in general, my code would not build. That's strange, since my "regular" host code has tons of C++11 stuff...

Answer (score 4):

If stumbling across this question while searching for a way to compile Genoils CPP-Ethereum build for Ethereum CUDA mining, my problem was solved by editing the CMakeLists.txt file in the  cpp-ethereum/libethash-cuda folder.

Where it states:

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
-gencode etc etc)
```

add "-std=c++11" after the semi-colon, as follows:

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS 
${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
-std=c++11
-gencode etc etc)
```